# Core Data Multiple Model Planning

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am designing a logging app and am currently figuring out how to structure the code.
I plan on using Core Data as the data storage and am trying to decide on the best way to structure the data before I begin.

I will be logging things like:

Movie - name, where viewed, how viewed, rating, time stamp
Videogame - name, when started, when finished, rating, how played,
Album -  name, artist, time stamp, how listened, rating
Book - name, author, started time stamp, finished time stamp, rating
etc.

There are some shared properties (time stamp and rating) but everything else is pretty specific. There are currently over 10 more items on top of the above, some without a 'name' as we would consider it.

My original plan was to make each an `NSManagedObject` and create some sort of InfoStamp property with an `NSDate` and `CLLocation` and another Rating object which they could all have.

Would 15 or more `NSManagedObject`'s be crazy and is there a better way to do this?
I don't want to make them all share a base `NSManagedObject` entity in the data model because Core Data will then store all the entities in the same table, slowing down performance. Obviously I can manually create the class hierarchy separate to the entity hierarchy, and would probably do so.

I also want to have the ability to search en masse through every single object for a certain NSDate for example. Would there be a way to do this?

If necessary, please ask me to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to go here is to use inheritance to model the common attributes.

In the model editor in interface builder, you can define an entity as "Abstract Entity". That means that it only exists to create other, more specific, so-called child entities. Your abstract entities could have a generic name such as `Item`, or maybe better (because more concrete), `MediaItem`.

When creating the child entities, simply select this abstract entity from the list as the "Parent Entity". It will now contain the same generic attributes. I would still recommend that you include a string, such as `title` for all these items, even if they have no obvious "name".

In the graphical model editor, you will now see the parent entity linked with arrows to the child entities.

This design is preferable to an additional entity (such as an info stamp) that only exists to hold attributes. It is much more cumbersome (in some cases) to search and filter via relationships than it is for simple attributes. Also, I think that such a collection of attributes is not correct from a conceptional standpoint because it cannot really be construed to be a meaningful "object" in the Core Data object graph.

One more idea: you might find it useful to design the parent entity to include a `type` attribute for convenient searching and sorting.

Comment: Really appreciate this detailed explanation. My only hesitance is because of this statement in #5 of objc-io: "Managed object models offer the possibility to create entity hierarchies, i.e. we can specify an entity as the parent of another entity. This might sound good, for example, if our entities share some common attributes. In practice, however, it’s rarely what you would want to do.
What happens behind the scenes is that Core Data stores all entities with the same parent entity in the same table. This quickly creates tables with a large number of attributes, slowing down performance."

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. That would be an issue if you had a huge object graph with one ancestor to *all* entities. I have seen this in one project where they wanted to include a `synched` flag - they ended up with one huge table!